# gmtset BASEMAP_FRAME_RGB transparency

Tags: linux, bash, shell, maps

I want to not have my basemap axes visible for an image I'm making in GMT with several plots in it. So far I have made them white using:

```
gmtset BASEMAP_FRAME_RGB = white
```

However some of the plots partially overlap and the white axes can be seen over the plots - any ideas on how to fix this? By making the basemap frame transparent ideally.

Comment: What does this question have to do with `bash` or `shell`?

Comment: I'm running the script in the Linux shell using bash, also it wouldn't let me tag things such as gmt, gmtset, psbasemap etc.

Answer (score 0):

In fact I've realised I can change the order I do the plots in so that the overlap doesn't matter - also replaced -B... with -G255 to plot on a blank square.